# Visual Studio 2017 Python scripting in C#

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

This is my Main File

```
        String filePath, path;
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {
            filePath = ofd.FileName;
            var sections = filePath.Split('\\');
            var fileNam = sections[sections.Length - 1];
            path=Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileNam);
            System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, destFile, true);
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine(); 
            var scope = engine.CreateScope(); 
            ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(path + "\\Image.py");
            source.Execute(scope);
             Object myclass = engine.Operations.Invoke(scope.GetVariable("pythonScriptClass"));
             object[] parameters = new object[] { fileNam };
             engine.Operations.InvokeMember(myclass, "Image", parameters);

         }
```

This is my Image.py File

```
import cv2  
import numpy  
class pythonScriptClass:   
    def Image(filename):  
       img=cv2.imread(filename)  
       gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   
       cv2.imwrite("result.png",gray)   
Image(filename)
```

I am getting error "IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named cv2'"

Comment: Have you installed `cv2`? For example pip install or something similar?

Comment: Yes.
if i run python on command terminal and write import cv2 i get no error

Comment: (Out of my knowledge,) I guess IronPython is running something like [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), and in that `venv` there is no `cv2` installed.